# Mapping Caps Lock to Ctrl, CentOS

Tags: x11, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a CentOS server (release 6.7). In order to do `tmux` shortcuts more quickly (`ctrl-b`), I thought of mapping the `caps lock` key as another `ctrl` key. How do I go about doing this?

I have looked up this up on Google and have tried adding `XKBOPTIONS="ctrl:nocaps"` to `/etc/sysconfig/keyboard` to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried it with CentOS (or any server), but with other systems, I used xmodmap. This probably only works with xwindows running, but I'm not sure.

Using xev, you can find the keyboard codes for various keys. I believe 66 is the caps lock key.

Then, in a terminal, type these lines:

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 66 = Control_L'
xmodmap -e 'clear Lock'
xmodmap -e 'add Control = Control_L'
```

Test it out to see if it works OK, then type:

```
xmodmap -pke >~/.Xmodmap
```

Now, any time you type xmodmap .Xmodmap, it will remap the keys.  To keep from doing this on every reboot, add a line ~/.xinitrc, like so:

```
xmodmap .Xmodmap
```

There is an article on something similar [here](http://efod.se/writings/linuxbook/html/caps-lock-to-ctrl.html)   You can search for "xmodmap" to find more articles.

Comment: Doesn't work on CentOS 7.